# How does one add widgets to a WordPress theme manually?

Tags: wordpress

I am using the MakeOver theme which doesn't have any support for widgets. I have installed the Ultimate Facebook plugin which provides a login using facebook button/widget. I want to add this widget to my homepage using MakeOver. What files should I edit? How do I add the widget manually?

Comment: Note, there is a bug in the theme. "Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\makeover2_0\functions.php on line 48"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better than trying to add the widget manually, I'll upgrade the theme to support widgets. See this http://www.wpreads.com/2013/03/creating-custom-widget-area-in-wordpress-theme.html and this http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link,

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39195/how-to-add-the-widgets-manually-to-the-sidebar

There you can see how to add widgets manually.